# How to get IP Address of User using .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application i have registration form, when user register i want to get his ip address of his system, how can i get using asp.net. help me please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

To get the IP address of the machine and not the proxy use the following code

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
```

Comment: @Lance: Good point. More info on that here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: than u Mr.Lance Harper it is working but what is the sencond one and third one it is not working

Answer (score 3):

HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress

Comment: Do note that for IIS7, `Request.UserHostAddress` for localhost returns `::1` and not `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString()
```